# how to implement updateMany in mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb

One of the property value has an extra space at the end of the string and totally there are 5000 Objects need to remove the space and update it. how to apply condition in updateMany

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var url = "mongodb://localhost:27017/";

MongoClient.connect(url, (err, db) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    var dbo = db.db("new");
    dbo.collection("compo").find({}).toArray((error, result) => {
        if (error) throw error;
        let finalvalue = [];
        result.forEach(req => {
            let nameComp = req.ComponentName;
            if (nameComp.substr(nameComp.length - 1) == " " && nameComp.length > 2) {
               let Compon = req.ComponentName.substring(0, req.ComponentName.length - 1);
                finalvalue.push({
                    "_id": req._id ,
                    "ComponentName": Compon
                });
            }
        })
        console.log(finalvalue);
    dbo.collection("components").updateMany({},finalvalue);
        db.close();
    });
});
```

I have referred through the below link but don't know where to apply the javascript condition https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.updateOne/#db.collection.updateOne

Comment: Use the [bulkwrite](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.3/api/Collection.html#bulkWrite) command instead with `updateOne` operations.

Comment: can you please give an example

Comment: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.bulkWrite/#examples

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.It may help you.

```
dbo.collection("compo").find({}, { "nameComp": 1 }).forEach(function (doc) {
    dbo.collection("compo").update(
        { "_id": doc._id },
        { "$set": { "nameComp": doc.nameComp.trim() } }
    );

})
```

Please refer this link: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-to-remove-white-spaces-leading-and-trailing-from-string-value-in-mongodb